# How can I append, or not, when writing to a file, based on a flag?

Tags: c++

I know this won't work, but it should make clear what I want to do:

```
if (append) {
   std::ofstream f(fname, std::ios::app);
} else {
   std::ofstream f(fname);
}
f << stuff; 
//etc;
f.close()
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 9):

One option, especially if there is additional logic in the if/else, is to use [open](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open):

```
std::ofstream f;
if (append) {
   f.open(fname, std::ios::app);
} else {
   f.open(fname);
}
f << stuff; 
//etc;
f.close()
```

Comment: I quite like this, since you don't hardcode the default.

Answer (score 7):

```
std::ofstream f(fname, append ? std::ios::app : std::ios::out);
```

will do it.

Reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/open